# object-fit: cover; stops working on dynamically added <img> (Safari bug?)

Tags: javascript, html, css, safari

I have a weird one... Just spent hours trying to tackle a Safari bug where object-fit: cover; stops working on a dynamically added img elements.

Maybe there is a workaround? Or maybe someone has any idea what is going on? I am unable to wrap my head around this one.

I have isolated the bug in this small test site:
https://safaribug.000webhostapp.com/

Just press Next page on Safari (it loads the same page just with a new next page URL).

[image: How if should look like]

[image: How it looks after page navigation]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone else stumbles open this bug, the solution that worked for me was to:

- Detect if the browser is Safari
- If it is, then once the HTML was put to the dom, loop through each image and force it to re-render. In my case I just removed srcset attribute and put it back again like so:

```
    document.querySelectorAll('picture.image > img')
            .forEach($img => {
              const srcset = $img.getAttribute('srcset');
              $img.setAttribute('srcset', '');
              $img.setAttribute('srcset', srcset);
            });
```

Not a solution I was looking for, but it works.

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue and your fix works fine, thank you very much! What a shape that Safari still didn't fixed this bug...

Answer (score -1):

you can use this for CSS

```
#bg {
  position: fixed; 
  top: 0; 
  left: 0; 

  /* Preserve aspect ratio */
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
```

or this code

```
html { 
 
 background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 

  -webkit-background-size: cover;

  -moz-background-size: cover;

  -o-background-size: cover;

   background-size: cover;
}
```

}

Comment: Why does this work? Can you provide some explanation here?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am aware that I can "fix" this bug with background-image, but this way I will lose the responsive image's aspect of srcset and I would like to avoid this if that is possible.